# C# normal forms application won't start on Windows 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I'm developing an application which should run on WIN 7, 8 and 10. It's running fine on WIN 7 and 8 but won't start on WIN 10. I tried even a simple "Hello World" form, but nothing happens on WIN 10. Is there another way that rewriting the whole thing as Universal App (which - I suppose - won't work on WIN 7 and 8)? MS does support standard forms applications on WIN 10 through their apps store, but I'm not sure that this is the way to go for a hobbyist. BTW I'm using VS2015 Express.

Comment: How are you attempting to run the app on Win10? As a standalone .exe or through VS?

Comment: As a standalone exe. It's working fine when I run it using Visual Studio.

Comment: Just a guess.. you are running the .exe file from the \bin\ folder, correct? Not the one in the \obj\ folder.

Comment: I tried bin/Debug, bin/Release, also tried the Program Files (x86) folder (where it should be once it's ready) and also tried running it from a memory stick. All of the above works on WIN 7 but nothing runs on WIN 10. When I click on the exe file I get the blue circle icon which keeps spinning forever. I don't see any process showing up in the task manager.

Comment: W10 certainly supports Winforms apps, I can create one and run it fine. Try creating a small dummy project and see if that will run.

Comment: That's why I did the "Hello World" test. Same result: nada. My WIN 10 is a clean installation. Is there a setting I may be missing ?

Comment: install Windbg (paort of Win10 SDK) and run your exe inside Windbg, when it stops at a exception, run **!analyze -v** and look what you see.

Comment: Will try that. I've never used it, so this may take a while before I come back with results ;-)

Comment: which version of .NET Framework are you targeting? If it's 3.5 or earlier, you need to install the framework, because it's not installed by default in Windows 10

Comment: I followed the example in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn745911(v=vs.85).aspx. I get exactly the results of the example with notepad.exe. I only get "Debuggee not connected" with my "Hello World" program..

Comment: My applications are targeting .NET 4.5 and 4.6

Comment: @DrewJordan (or anyone else willing to try): please download my Hello World VS2015 project and tell me if it runs on your WIN 10. Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_mcNCW4oRVOd21GNFFVbHdJT1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: works fine for me, running Hello World.exe from both from \Debug and \Release. I hate to be that guy, but have you tried restarting your PC? maybe something's goofed up...

Comment: Oh yes. Tried it over and over again on several days. Also tried it on another WIN 10 machine. Could it be related to my VS 2015? Would you mind shipping your Hello World.exe back to me ? ...Forgot to ask: did you just run the exe which is contained in the project I posted, or did you recompile it ?

Comment: ok, post it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the cause: my Avast virus scanner. Coincidentally, the other computer where it didn't work uses the same virus scanner. Didn't report anything, just kept scanning the application forever. Thanks to everyone for trying to help

Comment: I was having the same issue, thanks to you for this note about Avast! You really helped me with this answer!